# Find a store in a variable the full path of a folder if exist in BASH

Tags: bash, path, find

I need to obtain the full path of a folder (if exists) that match specific names. There is always one folder that matches the name.
E.g: the code must find, if exists, the folder with these possible names:

```
/home/user/myfolder
/home/user/myfolder_aaa
/home/user/myfolder_bbb
/home/user/myfolder_ccc
```

But **it must not match** any other "similar" folder, like

```
/home/user/myfolder_xxx
```

And if the folder exists I need to save in a variable the full path
Something like this is matching also unwanted cases and does not retry the full path:

```
path=`ls /home/user/myfolder*`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` with regex:

```
find ./home/user -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '.*/myfolder(_(aaa|bbb|ccc))?$'
```

To store the results in an array (as you don't appear to have whitespace in these folder names):

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -r f; do
   arr+=( "$f" )
done < <(find /home/user -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '.*/myfolder(_(aaa|bbb|ccc))?$' -print0)

# check array contents
declare -p arr
```

Comment: with this command I think myfolder_yyy matches and this is not correct. I need to match only those 4 cases -> myfolder, myfolder_aaa, myfolder_bbb, myfolder_ccc

Comment: The updated answer would match `myfolder_aaa_aaa` too.

Comment: @tripleee; Yes you're right. I had a typo of `*` instead of intended `?` (edited now).

Answer (score 1):

With a fairly small number of possibilities and only one target directory then this would be enough:

```
top_level='myfolder'

for end in '' '_aaa' '_bbb' '_ccc'
do
    name=$top_level$end
    if [[ -d $name ]]
    then
        var="$name"
        break
    fi
done

echo "$var found"
```